# Cannot read property 'promise' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I have this code:

```
var someFunction = {
    option01 : function($el){
      $el.css('color', 'red');   
    },
    option02 : function($el){
      $el.css('background-color', 'blue');
    }    
}

var my_div = $('.my_div');

someFunction.option01(my_div).promise().done(function() {
    console.log('option01 done');

    someFunction.option02(my_div);
});
```

I'm trying to reach some promise dependency, but regarding this code i have an error, which is: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'promise' of undefined`. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't make any sense.

First of all, `.promise()` is a method of a jQuery object, but `option01` doesn't return a jQuery object (in fact, it doesn't return anything). If you want `option01` to return `$el`, just do that:

```
option01 : function($el){
  $el.css('color', 'red');
  return $el;
}
```

Or, since `.css` is chainable:

```
option01 : function($el){
  return $el.css('color', 'red');
}
```

More importantly though, I don't see why you need promises *at all*. Promises are helpful when a function starts something which produces a result *later on*. For example, when a function starts an animation or an AJAX request, it can return a promise for when that animation/AJAX is completed.

`option01` doesn't do anything long running (such as an animation or an AJAX request). The `.css` calls take effect immediately, they're done as soon as they return. Therefore, when `option01` returns, it's simply *done*... so you can just do:

```
someFunction.option01(my_div);
someFunction.option02(my_div);
```

I'm just not sure what you're trying to achieve here. Is your sample code sufficiently representative for what those functions should actually be doing?

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything from functions, you need to return the element:

```
var someFunction = {
    option01 : function($el){
      return $el.css('color', 'red');   
    },
    option02 : function($el){
      return $el.css('background-color', 'blue');
    }    
}
```

But then not sure what you are looking for here, using `promise()`.

Answer (score 0):

please find below the link of working Plunker example

there was an error in selector, as string not closed. may be it was typo.

 return statement missing>
var my_div = $('.my_div');

http://plnkr.co/edit/3OJRF2wviNnX63jeH3aH?p=preview

```
var someFunction = {
  option01: function($el) {
   return $el.css('color', 'red'); 
  },
  option02: function($el) {
  return $el.css('color', 'blue');  

  }
}


$(function(){
var my_div = $('.my_div');

someFunction.option01(my_div).promise().done(function() {
    someFunction.option02(my_div);
});

});
```